# How to combine two @for or two @each (or combine both) in sass

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I want to use a @for in a @each using SASS. how can i do that such as matrix array in js?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use multiple `lists`, but I could give you more detailed info if you'd describe your usecase. The `@each` rule allows you to emit styles or evaluate code for each element of a `list` or each pair in a `map`. You can't have more then `two` items in a `map`. I think you mistake the `@for` rule.

You may checkout the [SASS Documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation)

**Note**: there is a `zip()` function which will allow you to combine lists into a single multidimensional list. [Here is the Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_functions_list.asp).